# Adding text with fontawesome in button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to generate some text underneath a fontawesome icon inside WPF:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="40" FontFamily="Arial Black" Foreground="White" Margin="5,30,0,0" fa:Awesome.Content="Folder">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            My Folders
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

The problem now is that it only shows "My Folders" and the fontawesome icon is gone - I can confirm that the icon works (when I remove the textblock it displays it).

Comment: I guess `fa:Awesome.Content="Folder"` should be somwhere inside of `StackPanel`. It is not clear what alignment you expect otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line

```
fa:Awesome.Content="Folder"
```

Works by setting `ContentControl.Content` to target icon character. So it sets `Button.Content` to character representing Folder icon in your case. But with the next statement you overwrite `Button.Content` with new value (setting it to `StackPanel`), so icon is gone. If you want button with icon and text - create one more textblock inside your StackPanel and use it for icon, then remove `fa:Awesome.Content="Folder"` from button itself. Or better use FontAwesome control instead of TextBlock, like this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="40"
        Width="300"
        FontFamily="Arial Black"
        Foreground="White"
        Margin="5,30,0,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="Folder" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        <TextBlock>My Folders</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="40" FontFamily="Arial Black" Foreground="White" Margin="5,30,0,0">
<StackPanel>
    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Folder"/>
    <TextBlock>
        My Folders
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```